# Tensorflow v0.12 image not displying after resized

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I manage to display an image using the following code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import numpy as np
import glob
import fnmatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def test1(path):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(path))

    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    label, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file,3)

    print(image)    


    with tf.Session() as sess:

        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(1):
            img = image.eval()      

        Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img)).show()


        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

    sess.close()

if __name__== "__main__":

    test1("./data/test1/1099.jpg")
```

however when I resize the image using the following code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import numpy as np
import glob
import fnmatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def test1(path):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(path))

    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    label, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file,3)

    print(image)    

    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224 , 224])

    print(image)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(1):
            img = image.eval()      

        Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img)).show()


        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

    sess.close()

if __name__== "__main__":

    test1("./data/test1/1099.jpg")
```

it give the following error message:

raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Thanks

Comment: Well what is the image dtype? print(image.dtype) or print(tf.DType(image))

Comment: @Steven Thank you for responding to my question. print(image.dtype) produce Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(?, ?, 3), dtype=uint8)
<dtype: 'float32'> , meanwhile print(tf.DType(image)) produce TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. You should accept your answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix it

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import numpy as np
import glob
import fnmatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def test1(path):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(path))

    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    label, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file,3)

    print(image)    

    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224 , 224])

    print(image)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(1):
            img = image.eval()      

        Image.fromarray(np.asarray(img.astype(np.uint8))).show()


        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

    sess.close()

if __name__== "__main__":

    test1("./data/test1/1099.jpg")
```

Thank people :)